# upgrade chroot version on centOS 5?

Tags: linux, centos, chroot

How do I upgrade chroot release on my centos 5 server? I want to install a service that uses a new capability available in later versions (--userspec) of chroot and I can't find any documentation of how to do it online.

Is it even possible? Do I need to build it from source?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uprade your chroot version you'll have to download `GNU coreutils` and build it from source.

1.First change directory to `/usr/local/src/` and then begin downloading the latest version of GNU coreutils with `wget`:

```
# cd /usr/local/src/
# wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.23.tar.xz
```

2.Extract it with:

```
# tar -xvf coreutils-8.23.tar.xz
```

3.After you've extracted it, `cd` into the folder:

```
# cd coreutils-8.23
```

4.In the `coreutils-8.23` folder, configure the source:

```
# ./configure --prefix /usr/local/src/coreutils-8.23/
```

5.Once the configure is complete, issue the `make` command and then install coreutils with `make install`:

```
# make
# make install
```

6.After you've installed the coreutils we can begin to install the new version of `chroot`. In CentOS chroot is located at `/usr/sbin/chroot` so change directory to that location:

```
# cd /usr/sbin/
```

7.Make a copy of the current `chroot` with:

```
# cp -p chroot chroot.original
```

8.And then copy the new version from `coreutils-8.23` to `/usr/sbin/` with:

```
# cp -p /usr/local/src/coreutils-8.23/bin/chroot .
```

9.Verify `chroot`'s version with:

```
# chroot --version 

chroot (GNU coreutils) 8.23
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

You should now be able to use `--userspec` as you want.